# NGram based Language detection William B. Cavnar and John M. Trenkle

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, n-gram

I am trying to implement the NGram based Langauage detection paper by William B. Cavnar and John M. Trenkle using https://github.com/z0mbiehunt3r/ngrambased-textcategorizer/blob/master/ngramfreq.py

```
import operator
import string
import glob
import os.path
from nltk.util import ngrams

#file which contains the language to be detected
filename = raw_input("Enter the file name: ")
fp = open(filename)
text = str(fp.read())
fp.close()

#tokenize the text
rawtext = text.translate(None, string.punctuation)
words = [w.lower() for w in rawtext.split(" ")]

#generate ngrams for the text
gen_ngrams=[]
for word in words:
    for i in range(1,6):
        temp = ngrams(word, i, pad_left = True, pad_right = True, left_pad_symbol = ' ', right_pad_symbol =' ')
    #join the characters of individual ngrams
        for t in temp:
            ngram = ' '.join(t)
            gen_ngrams.append(ngram)

#calculate ngram frequencies of the text
ngram_stats = {}
for n in gen_ngrams:
    if not ngram_stats.has_key(n):
        ngram_stats.update({n:1})
    else:
        ng_count = ngram_stats[n]
        ngram_stats.update({n:ng_count+1})

#now sort them, add an iterator to dict and reverse sort based on second column(count of ngrams)
ngrams_txt_sorted = sorted(ngram_stats.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse = True)[0:300]

#Load ngram language statistics
lang_stats={}
for filepath in glob.glob('./langdata/*.dat'):
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    lang = os.path.splitext(filename)[0]
    ngram_stats = open(filepath,"r").readlines()
    ngram_stats = [x.rstrip() for x in ngram_stats]
    lang_stats.update({lang:ngram_stats})


#compare ngram frequency statistics by doing a rank order lookup
lang_ratios = {}
txt_ng = [ng[0] for ng in ngrams_txt_sorted]
print txt_ng
max_out_of_place = len(txt_ng)
for lang, ngram_stat in lang_stats.iteritems():
    lang_ng = [ng[0] for ng in lang_stats]
    doc_dist = 0
    for n in txt_ng:
        try:
            txt_ng_index = txt_ng.index(n)
            lang_ng_index = lang_ng.index(n)
        except ValueError:
            lang_ng_index = max_out_of_place
        doc_dist += abs(lang_ng_index - txt_ng_index)
    lang_ratios.update({lang:doc_dist})
for i in lang_ratios.iteritems():
    print i
predicted_lang = min(lang_ratios, key=lang_ratios.get)
print "The language is",predicted_lang
```

It outputs 'English' every time I execute it. The computed distances are always the same for all the languages. I am not able to figure out the logical error in the above code. Kindly help me.

Comment: Do the files in `./langdata/*.dat` actually contain language data? This is the behavior you would get if they were all empty, or if they all contained the same text.

Comment: Yes they actually contain language ngram statistics data. If they were empty every ngram of the text would be assigned a max value(not found).

Comment: _Different_ language ngram data? Your program doesn't do what you thought it would do, so clearly one of the things you think you know is not true. Learn to understand and debug your programs.

Comment: Two things: lang_ng = [ng[0] for ng in lang_stats] should be lang_ng = [ng[0] for ng in ngram] and the tokenization part works better if we use word_tokenize. I think my little project is complete. Thank you everyone for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Comparing to the Cavnar & Trenkle code, it looks like

```
ngram = ' '.join(t)
```

should be

```
ngram = ''join(t)
```

(without the space)

I bet this is what's throwing off your stats.

Comment: Still the same.   ('english', 44578)
('french', 44578)
('spanish', 44578)
The language is english